# Visual Studio Code stores extensions and other settings for a specific Docker image

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have the following "problem". Let's say I set up a Docker container with Node on it and want to use it as a development container. I connect in Visual Studio Code via the extension "Remote - Containers" with the container and create a working folder, respectively I install some extensions e.g. Prettier.

If I now delete this container and create a new one with the same image, all extensions of the old container are automatically reinstalled and Visual Studio Code also tries to connect to the old working folder, which may not be available at all.

Does anyone know where this information is stored regarding the image so that I can delete it after I delete a container. I work on macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the files related to my problem. They are located in the following path under macOS:

~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/imageConfigs

The .json files contain information about the workspaces folder and the installed extensions.